# Como criar uma lista que dentro dela tenha duas mini lista

Tags: python-3.x

Como criar apenas uma lista que dentro dela tenha duas mini lista. E o tamanho é ideterminado, ou seja, enquanto usuario quiser adicionar valores dentro desta lista (interna) ele irá adicionar.

Comment: O que são "min lista"?

Comment: Tenta deixar mais claro colocando como você tentou fazer, acha que é, um exemplo ou pelo menos uma saída que você espera receber.

Answer (score 1):

É possivel fazer isso de diversas formas, o Python é otimo para se trabalhar com listas:

```
>>> lista = []
>>> mini_lista1 = []
>>> mini_lista2 = []
>>>
>>> lista.append(mini_lista1)
>>> lista.append(mini_lista2)
>>>
>>> mini_lista_1.append('valor 1')
>>> mini_lista_1.append('valor 2')
>>> lista[0]
['valor 1', 'valor 2']
>>>
>>> lista[0].append("valor 3")
>>> lista[0]
['valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3']
>>>
>>> lista[1].append("outra lista 1")
>>> lista[1].append("outra lista 2")
>>> lista[1].append("outra lista 3")
>>> lista[1]
['outra lista 1', 'outra lista 2', 'outra lista 3']
>>> lista
[['valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3'], ['outra lista 1', 'outra lista 2', 'outra li
sta 3']]
>>>
```

mais informações [aqui](https://panda.ime.usp.br/algoritmos/static/algoritmos/09-arrays.html)